# MYSQL Select all data except negative numbers or less than 0

Tags: mysql

I'm trying compute the Duedate to the CurrentDate but if the duedate didn't pass the currentDate the fine will get negative. I just want to get 0 if it's in negative numbers.

This is my code in computation

```
SELECT IssueDate,DueDate, DATEDIFF(DueDate,CURDATE())*5 AS fine FROM issue
```

Comment: Use `CASE` statement maybe?

Comment: Which numbers less than zero are not negative?

Comment: And which negative numbers are not less than zero?

Comment: NB Your title and your question od not agreed. Your title says you only want to select non-negative numbers. Your question says you want to select all rows and substitute a zero for the negative values. Which is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a condition like this :

```
SELECT IssueDate,DueDate, 
  IF(DATEDIFF(DueDate,CURDATE())*5 > 0, DATEDIFF(DueDate,CURDATE())*5, 0) AS fine 
FROM issue
```

It's just doing a max operation between the difference and 0, that way you can't have negative values.

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
SELECT IssueDate,DueDate, max(DATEDIFF(DueDate,CURDATE())*5, 0) AS fine FROM issue
```

Comment: **`MAX()`** is an aggregate function. The query in this answer would return 1 row. And the values returned for IssueDate and DueDate would be indeterminate.  I think the intention here was to use the function **`GREATEST()`** rather than **`MAX()`**